How do I find/get coordinates of all the nodes of a selected path in GIMP at once?
I wanted to use the map feature of HTML for giving a map of my country in my website. For tht i need coordinates of all states in the image of my country(India) tht i am adding. Since states are non-geometrical in shape, finding the coordinates of borders is getting a very hectic job.
I tried the path tool in gimp, made a path around a specific state, and using the pointer dialog i found the coordinates of all the path nodes, but it was VERY TIME CONSUMING!
Please suggest a better way to do this.

Just google it, here you can download the finsihed imagemap of india states:
https://www.mapchart.net/india.html

Thank you for the response.I want to put the image such tht when i click on one of the states in the image, it should direct me to the website showing information about the state
